# SQLite3 Python update whole row with a list

Tags: python, sqlite

#### System

- Python 2.7
- SQLite3

#### Info

I have table with the following structure:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER, number INTEGER, number2 REAL, letters TEXT)")
```

I got the following list

```
list_foo = [9, 1, 2.3, 'abc']
```

**edit:** In the table I already have fields, so the table should in this case be updated where id=9

#### Question

How do I update a row with my list variable?

#### Solution idea

```
c.execute("UPDATE foo SET VALUES = ? WERE id = ?", (list_foo, listfoo[0]))
```

But of course VALUES doesn't work. How do I instantly update the row without typing:

```
c.execute("UPDATE foo SET id = ?, number = ?, number2 = ?, letters = ? WERE id = ?", (list_foo[1], list_foo[2], list_foo[3], list[0]))
```

My actual table has more entries than this, so it would be a pain to type it like this.

**Edit 2:** If it's not possible and I have to use my long SQLite3 code, is it at least possible to have:

```
(list_foo[1:], list_foo[0])
```

instead of

```
(list_foo[1], list_foo[2], list_foo[3], list[0]))
```

Comment: If you don't change the id (which you probably shouldn't anyway), you can use `INSERT OR REPLACE`. Or you can get an ORM to write the queries for you.

Comment: Indeed id doesn't have to be changed, but the id's are already existing (sorry I didn't mention it, see edit). Therefore it has to be UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Update** (You can hack something by escaping the quotes, other than that I'm not sure if what you are looking for exists)

```
def quote_identifier(s, errors="strict"):
    encodable = s.encode("utf-8", errors).decode("utf-8")

    nul_index = encodable.find("\x00")

    if nul_index >= 0:
        error = UnicodeEncodeError("NUL-terminated utf-8", encodable,
                                   nul_index, nul_index + 1, "NUL not allowed")
        error_handler = codecs.lookup_error(errors)
        replacement, _ = error_handler(error)
        encodable = encodable.replace("\x00", replacement)

    return "\"" + encodable.replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\""


list_foo  = [2, 2, 2.5, 'abd']
tab_names = ('number','number2','letters')
dic = dict(zip(tab_names, list_foo[1:len(list_foo)]))

for x in dic:
  c.execute("UPDATE foo SET"+quote_identifier(x)+"=? WHERE rowid=?",[dic[x], list_foo[0]])
rec_con.commit()
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the table already has a list of id's. So I tried your answer with the update function: c.execute("UPDATE foo SET (number, number2, letters) VALUES (4,5.6,'def') WHERE id=1"), but this gives the error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: @NumesSanguis see hack; I don't think a pure SQL function exists for that.

Comment: Well if this is the only option I think a 3-line SQLite3 code is shorter :p Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: @NumesSanguis What is the 3 line SQL?

Comment: c.execute("UPDATE foo SET id = ?, number = ?, number2 = ?, letters = ? WERE id = ?", (list_foo[1], list_foo[2], list_foo[3], list_foo[4], list_foo[0]))

Comment: Ah, I see, you mean do the thing you were looking to avoid in the first place. You might be well served asking the question on a dedicated SQL site, who knows there might be a better way - if you don't ask you don't get.